# How to inherit proxied object in XML bean configuration

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have an AOP proxy bean defined as follows:

```
<bean id="someService" class="..FactoryBean">
    ..
    <property name="target">
        <ref local="target" />
    </property>
    <property name="preInterceptors"><ref local="serviceInterceptors"/></property>
    ..
</bean>
```

a target bean:

```
<bean id="target" class=".." />
```

and a child to the target bean:

```
<bean parent="target">
    <!-- set some properties -->
</bean>
```

I'd like to change the target bean to an anonymous bean, but maintain the child bean. The only problem is setting *parent* attribute of child bean to AOP proxy bean inherits from the factory bean and not the target bean. Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Anonymous beans will still get an id, but it will be one Spring auto-generates.

Comment: For what for you want o use the target bean?

Comment: @AndreiStefan and will I be able to access the anonymous bean from a different XML file?

Comment: @paul I'd like to do something like `bean parent="someService"`

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty, but it should work:

```
<bean id="proxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="target">
        <bean class="com.foo.bar.ExampleService" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="targetSource" factory-bean="proxy" factory-method="getTargetSource" />
<bean id="parent" factory-bean="targetSource" factory-method="getTarget" />

<bean parent="parent" />
```

Comment: Does the _class_ attribute have to be specified, on the child bean that is? The reason for making the target beans anonymous was to enable autowiring.

Comment: No, `class` can be omitted because there is the `parent` attribute.

Comment: This results in an error when I try to autowire the `ExampleService` bean.

Comment: Your question was about getting out the target object from `ProxyFactoryBean` without actually having an explicit bean for the target itself. What you mention now about autowiring is a different matter.

Comment: Sorry about that, the reason for using anonymous bean was to enable the use of `@Autowired` without having to change the bean children inheriting from the target. Do you think this is possible?

Comment: Does having a child bean make it impossible to use `@Autowired` without specifying the bean id?

Comment: What's the exception you get? I'm guessing it's something about multiple `com.foo.bar.ExampleService` beans for autowiring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58408/discussion-between-geoffrey-and-andrei-stefan).